# Is there a way to monkey patch array class in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to monkey patch array class from the rails console? When i try to run the following code i get this error.

```
class Array
  def push(obj)
    return
  end
end
```

I get the following error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1)
from (pry):2:in `push'
```

Comment: have you tried running this in irb?

Comment: Yes it just exits out of irb when i invoke the method. `[1,2,3].push(4)` just makes irb exit

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please explain why you would want to do this as it would not be recommendable and there is most likely a better solution to your actual question.

Comment: `Array#push` is an *extremely* common method that is used *everywhere* in Ruby, *including* IRb, the Rails console, the Ruby standard library, the Rails libraries, and so on. Re-defining a method that is used all over the place *will* break things. That's just the way it is. (And is the reason why that is a bad idea.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like something in the Rails console itself is making use of `Array#push` and will be using your monkey patched version once you've defined that.

The standard version of `push` is defined to take as many arguments as are passed to it, however your replacement version only takes a single parameter, `obj` and so isn't compatible.

This leads to the `wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 1)` error that you mentioned.

To replace `push` with a compatible version you'd use Ruby's `*` (["splat" operator](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/rubys-splat-operator/)) to define a method that can accept any number of arguments:

```
def push(*obj)
  # implementation here
end
```

Replacing `push` with a method that just returns without doing anything is likely going to cause quite a few problems. Perhaps update the question with some more details about what you're trying to do.